# python script to convert txt file to xlsx

Tags: python

Im trying to convert my .txt file into .xlsx file. I tried few options using openpyxl & xlsxwriter modules, but i was not able to get intended results. My text file is as below:
[Text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl7qo.jpg)

I need to convert it in Excel which look like this:
[Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Mvi.jpg)

Problem is, with the solutions i got till now i could only able to convert all the data in text in Excel, but i need few lines to chopped in between &  transposed it to first row. Please help me, as i have to deal with more text to excel convertions manually.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: post the code you have now, and the code you tired... this is not software writing service...

Comment: Please can you review both of these and amend your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show what you tried and its result and describe how exactly that was different from your desired result. Also, please give the example input text file as actual text ([edit] it into your question) rather than as a screen-shot image.

Comment: 1. step convert your textfile into python list like this:
[ [ 'TIME', 'TEMPS', 'XPT' ...], [ 0, 0, (other data)...], [ data from 2nd line], ... ]
2. step write into openpyxl  Workbook and thats all